# How to force Gmail to refresh after un/starring a message?

Tags: gmail

I have set my Inbox type to be "Starred first".

When I un/star a message I expect it to go immediately up (to Starred) or down (to Everything else).

Now I need to refresh the Inbox in order for this to happen.

Do you know of a setting or a script that will refresh the Inbox when I un/star a message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have keyboard shortcuts enabled, just type <kbd>g</kbd>, then <kbd>i</kbd>.

This will refresh the inbox.